# Recover phone data with a broken screen

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen, sony-xperia

Is it possible to recover data from my Xperia X whose screen is shattered(completely black). It's running Android Oreo and USB debugging is OFF. Unfortunately screen replacement is not available in my region for Sony Mobiles anymore :(

Comment: Is a pattern/PIN/password/fingerprint is set? Have you checked our [broken-screen tag Wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen)?

Comment: @Robert Ya, I have a pin set up

Comment: A PIN can be easily bypassed using an connected keyboard. As far as I remember the combination is RETURN <PIN> RETURN.

Comment: Yes. I am able to unlock the phone. But when I connect it with my PC, the default mode is "charging only". I have to change it to media transfer mode. How do I do it?

Comment: See Android key combinations and talk back mode https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6110948?hl=en

Comment: I tried this. I am able to unlock the screen. But nothing after that. Do we need to enable talkback ? On using those shortcuts, I hear nothing from the phone